# returning a variable of an if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, knex.js

hi i want to use a variable that i create inside a else statement to use in another function but i cant figure out how

the code >

```
if (!e){
               await knex('empresa').insert({
                   razao_social,
                   cnpj
               }) 
            }else{
                const e_id = e.id
                console.log(e_id)
                return
            }
```

i want to get that e_id variable to use in another function but i dont seem to be able to do it

Comment: just declare it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the variable in the global scope.
And only populate it inside the if statement.

```
let e_id;

if (!e){
               await knex('empresa').insert({
                   razao_social,
                   cnpj
               }) 
            }else{
                e_id = e.id
                console.log(e_id)
                return
            }
```